# adding play/stop button corona labs?

Tags: coronasdk

I'm totally new to Corona Game Development and I'm stuck on adding a **Play/Stop** button to the game if this helps here's the function that I use to play the background music :

```
  local backgroundMusicChannel
  local backgroundMusicSounds = {}
  if (backgroundMusic == true) then
  for i=1, backgroundMusicNumber do
        backgroundMusicSounds["bg" .. i] = audio.loadStream("sounds/bg" .. i ..".mp3")
  end
  end
  function playBackgroundMusic()
  if (backgroundMusic == true) then
        backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( backgroundMusicSounds["bg" .. math.random(1,backgroundMusicNumber)], { channel=5, loops=-1 } )
  end
  end

  function stopBackgroundMusic()
  if (backgroundMusic == true) then
        audio.stop( backgroundMusicChannel )
  end
  end
```

Comment: Show what you do so far.

Comment: Actually I didn't found the solution for that at all

Comment: So maybe it will be better start from [Chapter 1 — Creating an App](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/01/index.html) for you before go deeper :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Load audio stream
    local backgroundMusic = audio.loadStream( "backgroundMusic.m4a" )

--Play the background music on channel 1, loop infinitely
    local backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( backgroundMusic, { channel=1, loops=-1} )

--Pause Audio Stream
    local backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( backgroundMusic, { loops=-1 }  ) 
    audio.pause( backgroundMusicChannel )

--Resume after 3 seconds
    timer.performWithDelay( 3000, function()
        audio.resume( backgroundMusicChannel )
    end, 1 )
```